# how to get id of last inserted row

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a table in which following are the columns and their data-types

```
id=>AI,PK,int(11)
param_id=>varchar(45)
type=>varchar(45)
stationname=>varchar(45)
param=>varchar(45)
```

now when i insert a row in database:(database is MySQL, programming language c#)

```
insert into param_reference (Param_Id,Type,StationName,Param) values ('Res','" + Type + "','" + damName + "','maxQ')"
```

The row in table is like:

```
'1', 'Res', 'Reservoirs', 'B', 'maxQ'
```

param_id must be like 'Res1' where 1 is the auto-generated id.
But when we insert this row we can't insert 'Res1' coz id is unknown and we get only after insertion.
I did try as soon as after insertion of this above row

```
select id from param_reference where Type='" + Type + "',StationName='" + damName + "',Param='maxQ',Param_id='Res'
```

but it always returns null, it does not return the id.
How can i solve this ?
How can I get the id as soon as it is inserted.
Also it should be the last id inserted coz there can be many rows like:

```
'1', 'Res', 'Reservoirs', 'B', 'maxQ'
'2', 'Res', 'Reservoirs', 'B', 'maxQ'
'3', 'Res', 'Reservoirs', 'B', 'maxQ'
'4', 'Res', 'Reservoirs', 'B', 'maxQ'
```

but Res will be having the id part too..

so i actually want to update 'Res' as 'Res2' as soon as second row is inserted.

Comment: I think those are not duplicates, because in this case, getting the last insert ID is not the problem, but accessing it in the insert query.

Comment: my question is completely different.. why marked as duplicate i did see those solution and then asked this coz i didnt find my answer there..this is ridiculous..

Comment: Here's an alternative solution: you already have both parts of the string you want as a result stored already. Instead of storing `'Res7'` why not do `"Res"+id`?

Comment: By the way, I meant appending the ID to `"Res"` after you retrieved the ID from the database, where you'd only store the ID (and not `"Res"`, unless that string is not the same for every row).

Comment: @11684 i got it.. i did it already..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So a little trick to do this is to change you statement to this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (...) VALUES (...); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

and then insert the row with `ExecuteScalar` which will return you the id; you can then update the object accordingly. So the entire snippet might look like this:

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    int id;
    if (int.TryParse(result, out id))
    {
        // set the object's id here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try looking up the `last_insert_id()` function in MySQL.

Comment: it always returns zero

Answer (score 1):

@MichaelPerrenoud's answer is right. But in case you want to incorporate conditionals or use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in another query you should look at following link:

[**How to Get the Unique ID for the Last Inserted Row**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html).

Here is extract from reference:

> For **LAST_INSERT_ID()**, the most recently generated ID is maintained in
>   the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another
>   client. It is not even changed if you update another AUTO_INCREMENT
>   column with a nonmagic value (that is, a value that is not NULL and
>   not 0). Using LAST_INSERT_ID() and AUTO_INCREMENT columns
>   simultaneously from multiple clients is perfectly valid. Each client
>   will receive the last inserted ID for the last statement that client
>   executed.
>
> If you insert a record into a table that contains an AUTO_INCREMENT
>   column, you can obtain the
>   value stored into that column by calling the **mysql_insert_id()** function.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select max(id) from table
```

Comment: Probably a bad idea if other functions are also inserting rows into the table.

Comment: Okay, so the problem with this solution is it only works if there is one user using the system. If two users insert rows adjacently somebody is going to get the wrong id.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the max id from the table:
`SELECT MAX(id)  FROM param_reference`

Then append the result to Res and update it.